# How to include a count in join results?

Tags: sql, ado

I'm using VBA to build a SQL query with ADO.  I have a join query as follows:

```
select user.id,user.city,action.id
from user
left join
action
on
user.id=action.userID
```

I want to add a column that gives me the count of `user.city`, so that my results might look like:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| user.id | user.city | cityCount | action.id |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|       1 | DMZ       |         3 |         9 |
|       1 | DMZ       |         3 |        44 |
|       2 | KLF       |         1 |     23523 |
|       3 | DMZ       |         3 |         3 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I was thinking maybe I have to take an aggregate of this query and join it against the original query, like this:

```
select user.id,user.city,cc.cityCount,action.id,action.action
from user
left join
action
on
user.id=action.userID
left join
(select city,count(city) as cityCount from 
 (select user.id,user.city,action.id,action.action
  from user
  left join
  action
  on
  user.id=action.userID) 
 group by city) cc
on
user.city=cc.city
```

Is there a more direct way to get this count without having to write out (and execute) the same query twice?

Comment: what do you need in the `count` column? looks like your expected result is incorrect

Comment: @vkp, `count` shows the number of times a given `user.city` appears in the result set.

Comment: Which database and version? `count(*) over (partition by user.city)` with no `group by` will give you what you are looking for on SQL Server 2005 or greater and Oracle starting with maybe version 9i.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance, I think it's the Access engine, because the connection string includes `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select u.id, u.city, a.id,
       (select count(*)
        from user u2 join
             action a2
             on u2.id = a2.id
        where u2.city = u.city
       ) as cityCount
from user u left join
     action a
     on u.id = a.userID;
```